# Android can't play video issue

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, video-processing, android-videoview

Video URL not working in Default Android Media Player. For example:

http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4

The above URL is not working in default media player of android.

Comment: use exo player for video playing.

Comment: if you want then provide code for that.

Comment: can you post the code

Answer (score 0):

It is working with VideoView

```
    VideoView videoview;
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    try {
                // Start the MediaController
                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                        VideoPlayActivity.this);
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                Uri video = Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4");
                videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                videoview.setVideoURI(video);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            videoview.requestFocus();
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoview.start();
                }
            });
```